# Create and initialize bidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to create and initialize a bidimensional array in javascript inside an AngularJS application as follows:

```
$scope.invalidVote = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.arry1.length; i += 1) {
    $scope.answersCount[i] = $scope.arry1[i].arry2.length;

    for(var j = 0; j < $scope.arry1[i].arry2.length; j += 1) {
        $scope.invalidVote[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, What is the right way to do that?

Comment: I presume $scope.arry1 exists and is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$scope.invalidVote = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.arry1.length; i++) {
    $scope.answersCount[i] = $scope.arry1[i].arry2.length;
    $scope.invalidVote[i] = [];

    for(var j = 0; j < $scope.arry1[i].arry2.length; j++) {
        $scope.invalidVote[i][j] = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `$scope.arry1[i].arry2.length` will not work. It should read `$scope.arry1[1].length` - assuming arry1 is an array of arrays and not an array of objects that all have a property arry2 that is an array

Comment: This is something only the original poster can answer

Comment: You are right. It wouldn't be a 2 dimensional array otherwise, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `$scope.arry1[i]` is an array that contain other arrays and is already fill with values.
So your code should look like:

```
$scope.invalidVote = $scope.arry1;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.arry1.length; i += 1) 
  {
    $scope.answersCount[i] = $scope.arry1[i].length;
    for(var j = 0; j < $scope.arry1[i].length; j += 1)
      {
        $scope.invalidVote[i][j] = false;
      }
  }
```

'$scope.invalidVote = $scope.arry1;' declaring "invalidVote" like this ensure it contains the same amount of indexes.